# How to end Tests in Robotframework

Tags: swing, robotframework

I am testing a swing application, with the standalone version of Robot Framework and I am now at the point that my tests go through to the end.

However, Robot Framework will hang after the output of the report etc., leaving the prompt open.

Now i have two questions:
Is there a way that Robotframework closes this too?
And how does RF close Applications?

Comment: How do you start your tests in Robot?

Comment: with the command line using: 
java -cp "C:\path\to\robotframework-3.0.2.jar;C:\path\to\library.jar" org.robotframework.RobotFramework test.robot

Comment: it looks like the java process (im using the swing lib) is still going on after the test ist over

Comment: `RobotFramework` calls `RobotRunner` which implements `java.lang.AutoCloseable`. But below the Java surface some python interpreter is doing the real work. So maybe there is a problem with shutting down and returning an exit code to the Java process.

Comment: is there a error log for the RF itself, so i could check this?

Comment: This logs everything on debug level (and above) to a file "rf.log": `java -jar robotframework-3.0.2.jar run -l rf.log -L DEBUG test.robot`

Comment: Our Application using the system.exit()-Code to end. Does RF have Problems with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our software we are using the system.exit(0)-code to terminate. This also terminate the Robotframework.

After I created a parameter in the beginning, that checked if the Software is starting with RF, it exclude the system.exit and RF ends the test with no Problems.